# How to properly configure logback using environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have this in my appication.properties file:

```
logs.home=/var/log
```

and on my logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="${logs.home}" />

...
</configuration>
```

but when I start I have this problem: `logs.home_IS_UNDEFINED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<springProperty>`. Something like this:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="LOGS" source="logs.home"/>
```

You can learn more in the [relevant section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.logback-extensions.environment-properties) of Spring Boot's reference documentation.